# opening different Urls with mouse click on two different images C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv3.0

i am trying to open different urls when clicking on an image (each image will open different url) unfortunately, it kept on opening the first url only. The orientation of the image and the code for calling the url is put under the callbackfuction for mouseclick and are as shown below.

```
|        |        |
| Image 1|Image 2 |
|________|________|

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void * userdata)
{

  if(event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && image1.data)
  {

    //cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    const char * urlA = "http://www.google.com";
    wchar_t      urlW[MAX_PATH];
    std::copy(urlA, urlA + lstrlenA(urlA) + 1, urlW);
    if((int)ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", urlW, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW) < 32)
      ;
  }

  else if(event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && image2.data)
  {

    cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")"
         << endl;
    const char * urlA = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    wchar_t      urlW[MAX_PATH];
    std::copy(urlA, urlA + lstrlenA(urlA) + 1, urlW);
    if((int)ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", urlW, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW) < 32)
      ;
  }

  else if(event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN)
  {
    cout << "Right button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")"
         << endl;
  }
  else if(event == EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN)
  {
    cout << "Middle button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y
         << ")" << endl;
  }
  else if(event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
  {
    cout << "Mouse move over the window - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
  }
}
```

I dont really know where i go wrong as I tried declaring the second url as urlB but it still did not work. I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

PS (I am running the program on C++ with opencv 3.0)

Comment: why do you dispatching on image.data? If the orientation is consistent, may be just check the `x < window_width/2` condition?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the images' orientation, you can select the URL using `x` coordinate of the click event. For example, if your images are equivalent in width, you can just use `x < window_width/2` condition.

Example:

```
if(event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && x < window_width / 2)
```

To get window width, you can either get `cvGetWindowHandle` window native handle and then platform-specific functions on it or just calculate the width from images' sizes.

Comment: The images are equivalent in size...but im so sorry i dont really understand what you mean. (New in C++)

Comment: In your CallBackFunc you're accepting mouse click position, so you can determine what image has been clicked based on the `x` coordinate

Comment: So that means i would just need to declare a window_width that consist of the coordinates of the image?

Comment: you can do that too, but simply declaring window_width as a sum of 2 images' width would be fine too